# Display Brand Name Above Product Title in Woocommerce Cart, Checkout Page, Orders and Email Notification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, hook-woocommerce

Using the functions below I've applied a custom field to products added in Woocommerce cart and checkout page also to orders and notification email.

My question is how to show the brand above product title in cart, checkout etc. Any help will be appreciate.

```
// Display in cart and checkout pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'customizing_cart_item_name', 10, 3 );
function customizing_cart_item_name( $product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $product = $cart_item['data']; // Get the WC_Product Object


    if ( $value = $product->get_meta('my_custom_field') ) {
        $product_name .= '<span class="custom_field_class">'.$value.'</span>';
    }

    return $product_name;


}



// Display in orders and email notifications
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'customizing_order_item_name', 10, 2 );
function customizing_order_item_name( $product_name, $item ) {
    $product = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product Object

    if ( $value = $product->get_meta('my_custom_field') ) {
        $product_name .= '<span class="custom_field_class">'.$value.'</span>';
    }
    return $product_name;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to show a value fetched from database to be displayed in cart, checkout and emails ?

Comment: Correct, I want to show the field value fetched from db to be displayed in cart, checkout, emails and order.